# Listas de Listas en Python

Tags: python

```py
#Diseñar el algoritmo correspondiente a un programa, que:

#Crea una tabla (lista con dos dimensiones) de 5x5 enteros.
#Carga la tabla con valores numéricos enteros.
#Suma todos los elementos de cada fila y todos los elementos de cada columna visualizando los resultados en pantalla.
import random as r


listap=[0 for x in range(1,6)]
total=[]
for i in range(1,6):
    total.append(listap)
#print(total)
#print(len(total))

for k in range(0,len(total)):
    #print("k es ",k)
    for j in range(0,len(total)):
        #print(k,j)
        #print(total[k][j])
        total[k][j]=r.randint(0,35)
        #print(total[k][j])
print(total)
```

Buenas, deseo saber por qué en la lista de salida los valores no se modifican, es decir todos los valores o la mayoría deberían ser diferentes, ya que por cada índice lo cambio y no se actualiza. ¿Cuál sería mi error?

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay varias preguntas con el mismo problema. Pero casi no se sabe que es el mismo problema. Todo de debe a que la lista son objetos mutables, si tu asignas la misma variable (que contiene una lista) a cada posición lo que haces realmente es copiar la dirección de memoria, por lo que todos los elementos apuntan a la misma lista, lo que quiere decir que si modificas 1 modificas todas.

Comment: Solucion: haz `total.appen(list(0 for _ in range(5)))`

Comment: @Christian también puedes hacer `total.append([0]*5)`, ya que los enteros son inmutables.

Answer (score 0):

Donde dice

```
    listap=[0 for x in range(1,6)]
    total=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        total.append(listap)
```

debe decir

```
total = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    listap = [0 for x in range(1, 6)]
    total.append(listap)
```

En la versión original crear una `listap` que insertas repetidamente en la lista `total`.

Al hacer `total.append(listap)` lo único que has hecho es agregar una **referencia** a `listap`, no el **contenido** de `listap`. Como todas las referencias apuntas a la misma `listap` en RAM, cuando modificas un elemento de `total[][]`, estás modificando `listap`, y la modificación se ve reflejada en cada fila.

La solución es crear una nueva `listap` en cero para cada fila de `total`.

Está práctica la debes seguir cada vez que generes listas que contengan otras listas.

Comment: lo que sucede es que deso hacer tipo una matriz de 5x5

Comment: igual ya lo solucione me base en tu comentario muchísimas gracias y también por lo rápido que me contestaste